# After Google Play App Signing getting error while publish app on play store

Tags: android, google-play, publish

Any one got this type of issue after updating `google policies`. I got this error after `Google Play App Signing` for new apps uploading also.

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key before you upload it.

And I'm getting error like
[image: after uploading my apk]

And this is what I've in my play store account
[image: from play store]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got my answer. @Niraj hints helped me first. Actually at the time of `Google Play App` signing two `.jks` file I used.

1. With original one keystore, from which I was using to upload previously.
2. I created new keystore for upload. (But I didn't noticed after that.).

After creating 2nd one, this is my original keystore. Everytime I need to use this 2nd only for uploading.

**Hope this will help other also for that only I posted my answer.**

Comment: So how did you use the key from *Upload Certificate* ? There is an option to copy it but what to do after that?

Comment: no, actually you need to sign in with new key then upload will take sucessfully

Comment: I am not getting this, can you please explain

Comment: at the time of enrollment in google app sign, you need one .jks file, then for uploading it will ask for another .jks file. In which its clearly mentioned that this will be your upload key, use that key for further updates on play store. if didn't you got, 
pls explain your question clearly on SO then only can able to explain you.

Comment: I already uploaded and after change windows my key is gone

Comment: but after new version get error what i do??

Answer (score 5):

See the steps at the bottom of [this help page](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423), as well as the [diagram in the docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing). When you enroll in Google Play App Signing, you provide Google with the signing key to be used when packaging the app for distribution to users. This is the key you normally used to sign your releases for publishing. Once you finish enrolling in App Signing, you won't be using that key anymore.

As part of enrolling, you also received a new upload key from Google, which is only used between you and Google. When you generate an APK for publishing going forward, you should be signing it with that new upload key, and not the original signing key. The error message seems to be indicating you have signed your APK with your original signing key, and this does not match the upload key they were expecting.

Comment: yes you are right. still I'm using the original signing key. where I'll get the new upload key.

Comment: is there any way to extract this 2nd upload key without contacting Google Support. As far as I know, this upload key gets encrypted by pepk tool. I have the pepk file but lost my upload key