# You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. while updating app enrolled with App Signing program on Google play store

Tags: android, publishing, android-app-signing

I have uploaded an app and selected enroll it with "App Signing". I had no problems when uploading the first APK and it got uploaded successfully.

Today I tried to update that app and incremented the versionCode to 2 and versionName to 0.2 and used the same signing key as with the first APK, built successfully.

Now when I tried to upload it on google play it gives me following error:

[image]

I researched a bit and got to know that I have to link the **upload_cert.der** file  generated by play store with my keystore. I did that using the following command:

```
.\keytool -importcert -file ~\upload_cert.der -keystore ~key.jks
```

and again built the project but even then while uploading the APK I get the same error as above.

**I researched all the posts relating to it but everyone seem to be having this problem with "App Signing enrolled"**

Can someone guide me with the correct steps of using **upload_cert.der** to update the next version of the app

Comment: how are you signing the release apk? you need to use the same certificate you used with the original version

Comment: Yes I'm using same key file for signing it

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer here.

[Uploading after app signing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44077748/after-google-play-app-signing-getting-error-while-publish-app-on-play-store) . You've to use the 2nd certificate which you create at the time signing. This type of error comes only when you're using same .jks file for signing and uploading